# How to implement autosave on textboxes?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to implement autosave on a text box bound to the Name property of a view model.

I tried putting a timer on the key up event so that it executes the SaveName command if X secs passed after the last key up.

The problem is that the Name property on the VM is only updated when I move out of the text box. If X secs pass and I execute SaveName on the view model, the Name property doesn't have the changes.

How can I implement this? (other patterns to implement autosave are also welcomed)

Comment: 4.5 has got [an update to bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) which will handle situations like this very well.

Comment: WOW, now THAT is nice! I'll just have to use the DispatcherTimer until I can migrate to 4.5

Comment: Haven't seen a new revision that didn't come packed with puppy kisses and marshmallow rainbows.

Comment: @Will: While that is a nice improvement i'd rather have XAML 2009 working with compiled XAML already -.-

Comment: @H.B.: Ugh, tell me about it.  *I want my x:Arguments attribute already, damnit!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`Binding.UpadateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) to `PropertyChanged`, for `TextBox.Text` it is `LostFocus` by default.